# Want to restore Windows 7 from Linux Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, data-recovery, system-restore

I want to recover Windows 7 from Linux and I don't have the Windows 7 CD or any previous back up files. Please tell me if there is a way to recover Windows 7 from Linux because I do not want to boot it from the beginning as I have important files and they are in one partition.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a Windows 7 partition on your harddrive that you are trying to access through Linux? Or did you install Linux on top of Windows 7 on your drive?

Comment: yes, i have a windows 7 and i have install sth (a virus or sth like that, cant understand what is it) and the win7 do not open (i cant right good the english and I do not know so much the computers)

Comment: I believe he wants to run System Restore from Linux. He does not want to reformat the computer because he has important files on the boot partition.

Answer (score 1):

I had to recover some files from a notebook that had Vista but the drive had some problems (could no longer remap read errors). Fortunately it was just some drive meta data and windows files.

I was able to use the [system recover live cd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) quite easily to recover this - just burn this to a CD and boot/run off that. You will need a USB drive, a second good disk in the same system, or a working network and another computer/NAS drive.

However, this will not get you back your Windows 7 operating system unless you can use fsarchiver (I was not able to as the NTFS volume could not be mounted with r/w mode because of the damage to the meta data). After you copy off the files you will need to reinstall.

In my case, we didn't have the Vista CD (I'm in Korea right now and the CD was left in the U.S.), so we had to buy a new OS and got Windows 7 (much more happy with that anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to fix Windows from Linux without a lot of work and research but rescuing your files will be easy. Boot a Linux Live CD then plug an external hard drive or USB flash drive in. You will need to find out which drive to use. Run `fdisk -l` and look for your hard drive and the Windows partition. It will look something like this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 64 heads, 63 sectors, 4465 cylinders 
Units = cylinders of 4032 * 512 bytes 
   Device Boot    Start       End    Blocks   Id  System 
   /dev/sda1             1      2125   4283968+  07  NTFS/HPFS 
   /dev/sda2          2126     19851  35735616   0f  Win95 Ext'd (LBA) 
   /dev/sda5   *      2126      4209   4201312+  83  Linux 
   /dev/sda6          4210      4465    516064+  82  Linux swap
```

In this case, `/dev/sda1` would be the Windows partition. It will generally be the NTFS partition with the most blocks.

Next you need to make a place to mount the Windows partition. Under Ubuntu LiveCDs, `/media/windows` would be a good spot. So run:

```
mkdir /media/windows
mount /dev/sda1 /media/windows
```

Now you should be able to browse to the `/media/windows` directory and see your Windows files. Copy the files you need to keep to an external hard drive then shut the computer down and reinstall Windows (or just stick with Linux!).

Sorry about the necropost! Was browsing the homepage and didn't notice the 2010 datestamp...